# On load of page click trigger only once

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I have used the following script in a .phtml file

```
      require([
        'jquery'

], function ($) {
    $('#update-shipping-method-submit').trigger('click');

});
```

My issue is after loading of page is keeps on clicking & reloading, I want to click this id only once after page load.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code, hope its work for you.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
       // enter your code here.
});
```

Comment: require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
       $('#update-shipping-method-submit').trigger('click');
    });
});  I tried still same